# oracle : select from 2 select statements meaning

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I came across an if then else statement in oracle, but I am not sure what is the purpose of the two select count(*) statements. Can someone help me with that.
I need to undestand this to re-write the same in t-sql.
Thanks. Here's the code:

```
BEGIN
      IF (nEL_ID > 0) THEN
        select upperMatched||valueMatched INTO sResult
        from
           (
            select count(*) as upperMatched
              from HSIP.FY_ORT_VALUES ov
            where ov.FY = nFY and OV.EL_ID = nEL_ID
              and upper(OV.VAL_DESCRIPTION) = upper(sRESPONSE_STRING)
           )um,
           (
            select count(*) as valueMatched
              from HSIP.FY_ORT_VALUES ov
            where ov.fy = nfy and OV.EL_ID = nEL_ID
              and OV.VAL_DESCRIPTION = sRESPONSE_STRING
           )lm;
      ELSE
           sResult := '00';
      END IF;
       RETURN sResult;
```

SQL Server:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [hsip].[getMatchedFlags]
(
    @nFY NUMERIC(4,0) = 0,
    @sResponse_String varchar(250),
    @nEL_ID NUMERIC(5,0) = 0
)

RETURNS @sResult TABLE(FY NUMERIC(4,0),
Response_string  varchar(250),
el_id  numeric(5,0)) 

AS
BEGIN

insert into @sResult

--select * from (select case
SELECT CASE 
when (@nEL_ID>0) then 

SELECT(CONCAT(

 (select count(*) as upperMatched
              from HSIP.FY_ORT_VALUES ov
              where ov.FY = @nFY and OV.EL_ID = @nEL_ID
              and upper(OV.VAL_DESCRIPTION) = upper(@sRESPONSE_STRING)),

(SELECT COUNT(*) AS valueMatched
FROM hsip.FY_ORT_VALUES OV
WHERE OV.FY= @nFY AND OV.el_id= @nEL_ID
AND OV.VAL_DESCRIPTION= @sResponse_String))

ELSE

SET @SRESULT= 0;
return;
```

Comment: it's concatenating two counts.  in oracle || is concatenate string. much like + for sql server.  one from table FY_ORT_VALUES, and one from value matched so if count for 1st was 20 and count for second was 10 then you'd get a sResult of 2010.  ***Oracle is case sensitive*** (assuming default settings) so the numbers are being returned based on an UPPER case consideration and the second set is based on how they appear exactly in the database.  If nEl_ID <= 0 then you see a '00' returned.

Comment: Is case sensitivity enabled in both databases? neither? one but not other?  I'm assuming sResponse_String is a parameter passed in in the um sensitivity is being eliminated in lm sensitivity is being considered so if you had a VAL_Description in the table of `Florida`  if sResponse_Sting was `florida` it would match `um` but not match lm. so you'd see 10 as  a result.  but in SQL server w/ a case insensitive DB, you'd get 11!

Comment: Why are numbers being concatenated? That just seems odd. But in any case, if you translate this to T-SQL, please use the `CONCAT` function instead of the `+` operator since the `+` operator will add the numbers mathematically.

Comment: My thought is the oracle developer intended to add not concatenate the two values and you are porting the same logic to MsSql which was an error in Oracle. I suggest you research the business logic not just the coding logic on this issue. I have done a lot of porting systems from one sql platform to another. Always in this process we find lists of errors but the business generally assumes the code is correct. This is likely a case when it is not. I have never ported an application and found less than 3 errors in the process. Looks like you are on your first

Comment: This only really makes any sense if the counts returned are always 1 digit each.  if variable length counts then this gets confusing fast.

Answer (score 1):

`um` and `lm` are scalar subqueries (each returns a single row with exactly one column; in this case, the single value returned is a number, the count of something or another).

SQL (or at least Oracle SQL) allows you to use the result of scalar queries as expressions - in this case, as plain numbers. The "IF" branch sets the result `sResult` as the concatenation of these two numbers (after converting them implicitly to strings).

That doesn't make much sense to me; if the first count is 399 and the second is 1, then the result will be the string '3991' (not a number, but a string). By the way, if the first count was 39 and the second 91, you would get exactly the same result.

**Note** - as discussed in comments below this answer, I missed the main point of the original question. xQbert explains the meaning of the counts themselves in a Comment to the original question.

Comment: The queries are identical except for the case consideration.  So the first number will always be bigger than or equal to the second number.

Comment: @xQbert I don't think that is relevant; if you are referring specifically to my example, change it to 933 and 1 (same end result as 93 and 31).

Comment: Per question: "I need to undestand this to re-write the same in t-sql. Thanks. Here's the code:"...  Case sensitivity is off by default in SQL Server, on by default in Oracle.  To me that's very much different and may help explain why the queries are nearly identical; and in T-SQL given the same data may actually return different values than Oracle!

Comment: Oh... I didn't read the whole question carefully; I missed the part about T-SQL. I guess my answer is useless; I will delete it in a minute.

Comment: I wouldn't say useless.  Just amend comments etc.. Your point of combining numeric values as strings is great as it was also odd to me; so I appreciate you bringing that up; and you do explain um, lm well.

Comment: Ok thanks now delete your comments so we can tidy up and I will delete this one.  Still new to the forum getting more familiar with it.

Comment: Hi All, for the above oracle I tried to write t-sql equivalent i get errors near select keyword and else keyword. Is it syntactically correct?

Comment: @user3147594  you need to return a varchar data set not numeric the setting for 0 on the else should be '00' not just 0 based on the Oracle code.  and the function isnt' returning a table but a scalar value 1 output value.